# Reverse use of Haversine formula

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

Alright the title is not the best. What I want to do is to change the given parameters in Haversine's formula.

If we know the lat,lng of two points we can calculate their distance. I found the following formulas.

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)) 
d = R * c
```

Let's assume `R = 6371 #km`

The change I want to make is for only one given point and a given distance to find a point. Now for only those two parameters we create a circle with ofc infinite points around the given point.

Additionally I will create my program to start from the point -90,-180 up to 90,180. So we need to find every time either:

1. For the same latitude from our circle we have two points in the line. We want to find the one with the bigger longitude. So for the starting point of -70,-170 and a given distance of 100km we can have two points that have the same latitude (approximately): `-70,-167.37029` and `-70,-172.6297`. So I will pick the `-70,-167.37029`
2. For the same longitude, I do the same.

Any possible ways to reverse the formula? It has been some time since my last trigonometric problem... Thanks

Comment: I removed the reverse-math tag, which is for a different topic in foundations of mathematics.

Comment: @CarlMummert Feel free for any improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly let us use these variables:

- $\phi_1, \phi_2$: The latitude of points 1 and 2
- $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$: The longitude of points 1 and 2
- $r$: the radius of the sphere (in this case $6371$km)
- $d$: the distance that we want to find

Now the haversine formula is defined as:
$$\text{haversin}\left(\frac dr\right)=\text{haversin}(\phi_2-\phi_1)+\cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\text{haversin}(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)$$
and the $\text{haversin}$ function is defined as:
$$\text{haversin}(\theta)=\sin^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}2$$
where $\theta$ is some angle in radians.

---

**Note**: your angles are presumably in degrees. This may cause problems in the forumla. To fix this just multiply the degrees angle by the conversion factor of $\frac\pi{180}$. If you want to convert back just multiply by $\frac{180}\pi$.

---

As you may have noticed $d$ is nested within the function so to extract it we need to use the inverse haversin function given by:
$$\text{haversin}^{-1}(\theta)=2\sin^{-1}(\sqrt \theta)$$
Now applying this knowledge we can give a full formula for $d$:
$$d=2r\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\text{haversin}(\phi_2-\phi_1)+\cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\text{haversin}(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)}\right)$$

---

On the topic of your "circle" description. You want to have to a point on a sphere and connect it to another point finding $d$. Then you want find all points at distance $d$ from your point. To do this you would need to know $d$ by processing your two points using the haversin formula above. Once $d$ has been found you will be able to rearrange the equation such you can find a point. I am warning you though. This is a pretty hard rearrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaScript that implements the rearrangement of the formula mentioned in the answer.

The "reverse use of the Haversine formula" is in function `calculateOuterBounds`, which calculates the adjustment needed to latitude or longitude to find the points due north, south, east or west on the circle on the surface of the sphere that has `radius` centered at given `location`.

Also included is an implementation of the Haversine formula, `distance`. Plus some sample code to show how to use the reverse form.

```
function circle (location, radius) {
    const R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km

    function distanceTo(point) {
        return distance(location, point)
    }

    function distance(a, b) {
        const lat1 = deg2rad(a.latitude)
        const lat2 = deg2rad(b.latitude)
        const deltaLatitude = deg2rad(a.latitude - b.latitude);
        const deltaLongitude = deg2rad(a.longitude - b.longitude); 
        const x = 
            haversine(deltaLatitude) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * haversine(deltaLongitude)
        const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(x), Math.sqrt(1-x))
        return R * c; // Distance in km
    }

    function calculateOuterBounds() {
        const deltaLatitude = radius / R
        const deltaLongitude = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(haversine(radius / R) / (Math.cos(deg2rad(location.latitude)) ** 2)))

        return {
            deltaLatitude: rad2deg(deltaLatitude), 
            deltaLongitude: rad2deg(deltaLongitude)
        };
    }

    function haversine(theta) {
        return Math.sin(theta/2) ** 2
    }

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI/180)
    }

    function rad2deg(rad) {
        return rad * (180/Math.PI)
    }

    return {distanceTo, calculateOuterBounds}
}


/////////////////////////////////////////
// sample code to show how to use

function adjust(point, by) {
    var adjusted = {...point}
    adjusted.latitude += by[0]
    adjusted.longitude += by[1]
    return `${adjusted.latitude}, ${adjusted.longitude}`
}

const theSpire = {latitude: 53.34982169772085, longitude: -6.260252860015207}
const radius = 2

const outerBounds = circle(theSpire, radius).calculateOuterBounds() 

const bounds = {
    north: adjust(theSpire, [outerBounds.deltaLatitude, 0]),
    south: adjust(theSpire, [-outerBounds.deltaLatitude, 0]),
    east: adjust(theSpire, [0, outerBounds.deltaLongitude]),
    west: adjust(theSpire, [0, -outerBounds.deltaLongitude])
}

console.log(`the point ${radius}km north of the spire is ${bounds.north}, and the point the same distance to the west is ${bounds.west}`)
```