# Reverse Haversine to find point

Tags: geometry, spheres

I need help with rearranging the Haversine formula, which is commonly used for calculating the Great Circle (GC) distance between two known points. I know the first point, I know the longitude of the second point and I know the GC distance to the second point. What I don't know and need to calculate is the latitude of the second point.

For example:

lat1 = 0
lon1 = 0
lat2 = ?
lon2 = 0
GC distance = 500KM

Someone already posted basically the same question but the only given answer misses the point. See [Reverse use of Haversine formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474602/reverse-use-of-haversine-formula) (I do not have enough points on this site to comment and revive that particular question).

tldr; please rearrange the haversine formula (see below) to let me solve for lat2.

---

**Haversine formula**
$$d=2r\,sin^{-1}\Biggl(\sqrt{sin^2\biggl(\frac{lat2-lat1}{2}\biggr)+cos(lat1)\,cos(lat2)\,sin^2\biggl(\frac{lon2-lon1}{2}\biggr)}\Biggr)$$

Comment: welcome to MSE! Please use math LaTeX to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Longitude is relatively easy to calculate

$$
lon2 = lon1 + 2 sin^{-1}(\sqrt{sec(lat1) sec(lat2) sin^2(\frac{d}{2r})-sec(lat1) sec(lat2) sin^2(\frac{lat2 - lat1}{2} )})
$$

Latitude is a mess. I'm not even going to bother transcribing this into LaTex.

```
lat2 = sec^(-1)(((8 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) sin^6((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) + (4 sqrt(tan^2(lat1) (4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) - cos^2(d/r) sec^2(lat1) + tan^2(lat1) + 1)) sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) - (12 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) - 4 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) - (4 sqrt(tan^2(lat1) (4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) - cos^2(d/r) sec^2(lat1) + tan^2(lat1) + 1)) sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) + (2 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) tan^2(lat1) sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) + (6 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) + 2 cos(d/r) sec(lat1) + (tan^2(lat1) sqrt(tan^2(lat1) (4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) - cos^2(d/r) sec^2(lat1) + tan^2(lat1) + 1)))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) + sqrt(tan^2(lat1) (4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) - cos^2(d/r) sec^2(lat1) + tan^2(lat1) + 1))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) - (cos(d/r) sec(lat1) tan^2(lat1))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1) - (cos(d/r) sec(lat1))/(4 sin^4((lon1 - lon2)/2) - 4 sin^2((lon1 - lon2)/2) + tan^2(lat1) + 1))/(cos^2(d/r) sec^2(lat1) - tan^2(lat1)))
```